How to make sure a virtual method gets called just after the constructor?
I have a base class with an abstract virtual function fv() which is only implemented in derived classes. I want to make sure that the fv() of the derived classes is called in or immediately after the constructor.
However, when I call the virtual function in the constructor, I get a warning, and the code can't be linked:

undefined reference to `A::fv()'

I also tried this:
class A{
    A() {fx()};
    virtual void fv() = 0;
    void fx(fv());
}
    
class B : public A {
    B():A();
    void fv() {};
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
     B::b{];
}

This code compiles, but when I run it I get:
pure virtual method called
terminate called without an active exception
Aborted

Of course, I can manually call fv() in the constructor of B, but this seems inelegant and not safe, because someone deriving a class from my A might forget to call fv() (which could lead to undefined behavior in my real code).
Is there an "automatic" way to make sure that the fv() of derived classes will be called as soon as the object is instantiated?

This won't compile. Make sure you post a [mcve]. Also add the necessary #includes.

Nope. You've made A extensible, so people can extend it without your knowledge. This is one of the reasons why init() -style methods are a big no-no. CTAD might be the pattern you are looking for, if you can replace runtime polymorphism with compile-time.

This is a common problem. To understand the fundamental issue here, consider class C: public B. The question states "after the constructor" but the implied constructor is both B::B and the constructor of the complete object. These two might not be the same, as shown by C.

It sounds like the builder pattern might fit your needs.

Can you use CRTP ? it is likely the only way to call a derived function in the base constructor

@AhmedAEK although CRTP can allow a base class to call derived methods without using virtual, the base constructor (or base destructor) still can't call derived methods since the derived object simply doesn't exist at that stage.

@RemyLebeau compilers do allow it, it is just UB if it accesses any member of derived.

@AhmedAEK Calling a method on a non-existent object is UB, regardless of whether it accesses any members.

You can't call a virtual method inside the base class constructor. The derived class object doesn't exist yet. And there is no automatic way to call a method after a constructor.
One common way to handle this is to make the constructor(s) private so no instances can be created directly, and then write a separate factory that can create the instances.  This way, every instance must be created by your factory, and the factory can do whatever it needs after calling a constructor before returning the new instance.
For example:
#include <unordered_map>
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

class A {
protected:
    A() { ... }

public:
    using A_ptr = std::unique_ptr<A>;
    using createFunc = std::function<A_ptr()>;

    virtual ~A() { ... }
    
    virtual void fv() = 0;
    void fx() { ... }

    static void registerCreator(const std::string& name, createFunc creator) {
        m_creators[name] = std::move(creator);
    }

    static A_ptr create(const std::string& name) {
        auto instance = m_creators.at(name)();
        instance->fv();
        return instance;
    }

private:
    static std::unordered_map<std::string, createFunc> m_creators;
};

std::unordered_map<std::string, A::createFunc> A::m_creators;
    
class B : public A {
protected:
    B() { ... }

public:
    ~B() { ... }

    void fv() override { ... }
    static A_ptr createMe() { return A_ptr(new B); }
};

class C : public B {
    C() { ... }

public:
    ~C() { ... }

    void fv() override { ... }
    static A_ptr createMe() { return A_ptr(new C); }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    A::registerCreator("B", &B::createMe);
    A::registerCreator("C", &C::createMe);

    auto b = A::create("B");
    b->fx();

    auto c = A::create("C");
    c->fx();
}

Demo

Factory method cannot be futureproofed for other derived classes like OP would want. Basically, factory method has the same issues as simply calling fv in B constructor.

@Yksisarvinen yes, it can. The factory can be templated. Or it can use a registration system to discover new classes at runtime. There are many ways to implement a factory. But the point is to design the classes so the factory must be used to create them, that way there is a single point of initialization that can be extended as needed.

Please show an example how do you make sure that class C: public A is forced to use factory method you created (with factory method knowing nothing about existence of C). I have no idea how it could be achieved, and I suppose the same could be said about OP.

I recommend looking up the self-registering factory. It's a pattern I'm quite fond of, especially if your team owns the factory, but other teams need to create objects from it. They would own the objects they create and not have to touch your factory. At the cost of boilerplate, it greatly minimizes the amount of touches required to add more objects to the factory.

I actually have a toy self-registering factory: https://gitlab.com/sweenish/blind75/-/blob/main/Design_Patterns/Creational/Self_Registering/02-self_registering_factory.cpp?ref_type=heads

I updated my answer with an example factory.

You can achieve this by hiding the constructors and using a factory-like method to create objects.
The only way to create objects is to use the Factory method since the B constructor is private.
The Factory method creates the object and calls the fv method.
Now, when you call the fx method you are sure the fv method has already been called.
For example:
class A{
protected:
    A() {};
public:
    virtual void fv() = 0;
    void fx(){}
};

class B: public A 
{
    B():A(){};
public:
    void fv() {};
    static B Factory()
    {
        B obj;
        obj.fv();
        return obj;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
     B b = B::Factory();
     b.fx();
}

Note that you will have to use move and copy constructors for more complex objects of B.
